# Is my sugar daddy a scam

Tags: cryptocurrency, sugar-daddy

I recently started talking to this guy few weeks ago and then he asked if I’m interested in being his sugar baby and then he wants my account number and routing so he can send me direct deposit then I would have to make it into Bitcoin… Idek if this is real or a scam I even told him to send me his id and social security lol he sent them but I’m like still iffy or maybe I have trust issues idk I need helpppp! Also never met him in person he’s out of state.

Comment: The answer to "Is my sugar daddy a scam?" is always yes.

Comment: Yes.  If you aren't having sex with him (the traditional definition of sugar daddy), it's a scam.

Comment: @jamesqf There's nothing that stops it from also being a scam if she is having sex with him.

Comment: What if we’ve talked abt sexual things but out of respect from him he didn’t wanna pressure me for pics and stuff

Comment: @KellyLenae In that case, it's still a scam (the fact that there's also a sexual side doesn't mean that he's not trying to steal from you as well, or to make you his accomplice in stealing from someone else). You should stop all contact with him, and (unfortunately) be prepared for him to try to use sexual details from your conversation to blackmail you. *You should not go along with this blackmail.* The only thing that obeying any further instructions he gives you will do is to give him even more things to blackmail you with.

Comment: @RLH: True, but my point is that it MAY be a scam if she's having sex, but it CERTAINLY is a scam if she's not.  (And for the OP, pictures are not sex.)

Comment: I continue to be fascinated with how there can be so many posts asking about sugar daddies on this site, when all the questions are ultimately the same ("is my sugar daddy a scam") and all the answers are also the same ("yes").

Answer (score 12):

I can answer the question base on the title:

> Is my sugar daddy a scam

The answer is yes. Everything else they did from asking for your account number and routing, to cryptocurrency, to them giving you their SSN and id; screams scam even louder.

Comment: Money.SE's Razor for Scam Identificaton: "TLDR: Yes. It's a scam until proven legitimate."

Answer (score 11):

Yes you are being scammed.

A sugar-daddy relationship is supposed to have your daddy paying you for some sugar. If you are not giving your daddy some sugar then its *NOT* a sugar daddy relationship, it's a scam. If you are being paid for sugar, then you should be doing some searches on the risks of sex work. If you are giving some sugar *and* being paid by weird bank transfers then that's also a scam.

If you're being paid to take money and convert it to Bitcoin and send it back to your sugar daddy then you're being used to launder money. He is getting money from somewhere, its probably stolen accounts. He sends the money to your bank account then you send him back Bitcoin that he can spend or convert to clean cash.

When the stolen accounts are discovered the banks will come after YOUR account for their money back. But you will have already spent that money buying Bitcoin. So in the end you're a victim here too.

Stop contacting this person. Find above board ways to make money, sugar daddy relationships are nearly always a scam. The ones that are not scams carry their own risks for physical and sexual abuse and are not a good idea either.

Comment: This is mostly very good advice, but could be reworded (maybe remove the second paragraph) to avoid the implication that payment for conversations/pictures makes the situation less scammy. There's nothing stopping a scammer from simultaneously setting up a victim as a laundering mule, exploiting them, and collecting extortion material).

Comment: @RLH - What I really want to say is "Is he paying you to fornicate with him?... If the answer is no then he's a scammer. If the answer is yes, then lets talk about the risks of sex work"

Comment: How about also adding something like "(If you are being paid for sugar and the payment is via sketchy bank transfers, you are both being scammed and subject to the risks of sex work.)"

Comment: This is not legal advice, but the money laundering mule is also liable in court.

Answer (score 4):

Prostitutes can be paid the same way that a clerk is paid at a convenience store, or the same way that their friends would pay them for splitting the bill at a restaurant. Any range of legal sex work or subsidized companionship is not different.

If a larger transaction is desired (apps and credits cards have arbitrary
limits between $2000 and $10,000, but there is no legally mandated reason for that), then a wire transfer can be done - which would need your bank account number and routing number. But that would be it, there would be no additional work for you to do, no purchasing of bitcoin, no sending the money to further places and back.

Comment: The $10,000 limit is related to money laundering. Some cards and banks avoid these limits to reduce the need to report to regulation agencies. For other limits (including the $10,000) it's a risk calculation. i.e. "How much can I lend this person and have a fair expectation of they not defaulting"

Comment: Sending bank account number and routing number can lead to bank identity theft. https://www.thesimpledollar.com/banking/is-it-safe-to-share-bank-account-information/ https://consumerboomer.com/what-can-someone-do-with-your-bank-account-and-routing-number/ https://pocketsense.com/safe-give-account-number-routing-number-someone-6908.html

Comment: @Mindwin correct, PRIMARILY risk calculation. Ambiguously saying "related to money laundering" fails to give any insight into the actual legal reality or its lack of relevance here, but correct in that there is some reporting banks dont want to deal with. A wire transfer (and even ACH) inherently needs a bank account and routing number, and one must ask for wire transfer instructions to accomplish it. Our system offers no way to distinguish between a legitimate request and a malicious request, and that reality leaves us no ability to immediately call something a scam from that alone.